# Android - Snackbar Cover my View

Tags: java, android

Why Snackbar cover my view

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reload"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/reload"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/complist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:fadeScrollbars="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:text="@string/send"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

java code used to show snake bar

```
 private CoordinatorLayout _CoordinatorLayout;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compition, null);

        _CoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fullview);

}

Snackbar.make(_CoordinatorLayout , message , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

here is screen shot

[image]

what I miss ??

Comment: can you post how that looks in image

Comment: @johnrao07: From the edit history it seems that, you removed the image from question.

Comment: its ok I add it again

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) here says:

> Snackbars appear above all other elements on screen and only one can
>   be displayed at a time.

So, Snackbar will cover your view, just like a Toast.

Comment: no its shouldn't block my buttons , please have a look https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage , it says Don’t block the floating action button

Comment: @MinaFawzy yes it doesn't block the floating button because it moves it up a bit when Snackbar is displayed.

Comment: I mean its the same , it block my buttons , it shouldn't do this behavior

Comment: No it's not the same. Your button belongs to the `android.widget.Button` class, but the Floating Action Button belongs to the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`. The `FloatingActionButton` extends the `ImageButton` and adds the floating functionality to it.